# Narrowing function return type with type guards

Tags: typescript, narrowing

I have a TypeScript function that parses some JSON and runs it through a type guard to ensure that the data was valid so that the rest of the compile-time code knows that it's dealing with an object that actually abides by the expected interface.

However, I'm having a hard time making TypeScript enforce that a type guard has been run. Apparently `JSON.parse` returns `any`, which is assignable to any other type and therefore checks, even if I specify a non-`any` return type.

```
const validPerson = `{"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe"}`;
const invalidPerson = `{"foo": 123}`;

interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

interface PersonGetter {
    (json: string): Person | undefined;
}

function isPerson(o: any): o is Person {
    return typeof o.firstName === "string" && typeof o.lastName === "string";
}

// BAD: Type checks, but it's overly permissive. `JSON.parse` could return anything.
const getPerson1: PersonGetter = (json) => {
    const o = JSON.parse(json);
    return o;
}

// GOOD (kinda): Requires type guard to pass.
// `unknown` requires TS 3, which is fine in general, but bad for me.
// Also, I feel like having to remember to case the return from `JSON.parse` is a responsibility the programmer shouldn't bear.
const getPerson2: PersonGetter = (json) => {
    const o: unknown = JSON.parse(json);
    if (isPerson(o)) {
        return o;
    } else {
        return undefined;
    }
}

// GOOD (kinda): Requires type guard to pass. Works in TS 2.8.
// Still, not great that I have to cast the return value from `JSON.parse`, but I could probably work around that.
type JSONPrimitive = string | number | boolean | null;
type JSONValue = JSONPrimitive | JSONObject | JSONArray;
type JSONObject = { [member: string]: JSONValue };
interface JSONArray extends Array<JSONValue> {}

const getPerson3: PersonGetter = (json) => {
    const o: JSONValue = JSON.parse(json);
    if (isPerson(o)) {
        return o;
    } else {
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20validPerson%20%3D%20%60%7B%22firstName%22%3A%20%22John%22%2C%20%22lastName%22%3A%20%22Doe%22%7D%60%3B%0D%0Aconst%20invalidPerson%20%3D%20%60%7B%22foo%22%3A%20123%7D%60%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Person%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20firstName%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20lastName%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20PersonGetter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(json%3A%20string)%3A%20Person%20%7C%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isPerson(o%3A%20any)%3A%20o%20is%20Person%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20typeof%20o.firstName%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22string%22%20%26%26%20typeof%20o.lastName%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22string%22%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20BAD%3A%20Type%20checks%2C%20but%20it's%20overly%20permissive.%20%60JSON.parse%60%20could%20return%20anything.%0D%0Aconst%20getPerson1%3A%20PersonGetter%20%3D%20(json)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20o%20%3D%20JSON.parse(json)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20o%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20GOOD%20(kinda)%3A%20Requires%20type%20guard%20to%20pass.%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%60unknown%60%20requires%20TS%203%2C%20which%20is%20fine%20in%20general%2C%20but%20bad%20for%20me.%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Also%2C%20I%20feel%20like%20having%20to%20remember%20to%20case%20the%20return%20from%20%60JSON.parse%60%20is%20a%20responsibility%20the%20programmer%20shouldn't%20bear.%0D%0Aconst%20getPerson2%3A%20PersonGetter%20%3D%20(json)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20o%3A%20unknown%20%3D%20JSON.parse(json)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(isPerson(o))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20o%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20GOOD%20(kinda)%3A%20Requires%20type%20guard%20to%20pass.%20Works%20in%20TS%202.8.%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Still%2C%20not%20great%20that%20I%20have%20to%20cast%20the%20return%20value%20from%20%60JSON.parse%60%2C%20but%20I%20could%20probably%20work%20around%20that.%0D%0Atype%20JSONPrimitive%20%3D%20string%20%7C%20number%20%7C%20boolean%20%7C%20null%3B%0D%0Atype%20JSONValue%20%3D%20JSONPrimitive%20%7C%20JSONObject%20%7C%20JSONArray%3B%0D%0Atype%20JSONObject%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bmember%3A%20string%5D%3A%20JSONValue%20%7D%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20JSONArray%20extends%20Array%3CJSONValue%3E%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20getPerson3%3A%20PersonGetter%20%3D%20(json)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20o%3A%20JSONValue%20%3D%20JSON.parse(json)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(isPerson(o))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20o%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Option 3 would work for me, but it uses [proposed JSON types that are still up for debate](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1897#issuecomment-424163618) and still puts the responsibility on the implementor (who could just as easily not use a type guard at all and still think they're abiding by the interface).

It would appear that `JSON.parse` returning `any` is the source of my problem here. I'm already running in `strict` mode, but it would appear that it still allows something explicitly typed as `any` to be expanded to the explicit return type of the function.

Is there another way to tell TypeScript that the return value of the function must be the return type specified in the interface that it implements and not `any`?

Comment: I don't understand what you're expecting and am confused by the purpose of including `getPersonWithUnknown`.  What's wrong with `getPerson` and omitting the (unnecessary) type declaration?  The if block at the end is going to make sure the Type of the returned object is correct.  Is your point that you don't want any code in your application mistakenly returning the wrong type and this is just an example?  If so use some kind of type guard after any function that returns any type like you do in the third function.

Comment: `getPersonWithUnknown` was just an example of a function that was properly throwing a type error (since `unknown` can't be assigned to `Person`). The final `getPerson` function builds off of that. What I'm asking is if I have an interface for a function that is supposed to return a `Person` or `undefined`, how do I make TypeScript not say that a function that returns `any` is acceptable?

Comment: Slightly off-topic: how is `Person?` not a syntax error in the Playground?

Comment: The purpose of `any` is to skip compile-time tests, so I don't think what you want is possible.  It's a good question if I'm wrong and there is actually a way.

Comment: @Aaron it actually causes a function definition to disappear from compiled code, leaving only body as a block.

Comment: @AndrewO the third one would work with `any` but there is no question-mark in type syntax in TypeScript. In your case the type is `Person | undefined` and will be inferred.

Comment: Good point, @DanielGimenez . I wonder if the basic issue is just that `JSON.parse`'s return type should be more constrained. I overrode it be the [`JSONValue` type here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1897#issuecomment-424163618) and it now requires the type guard in order to type check. That might be a solution. I'm just not sure if I want to make a blanket change to a core function like that...

Comment: I added the `?` as an after thought, so that might be causing issues. `Person | undefined` would be fine. Or, for the sake of this example, throwing an error if the type guard returns false. In the real world I might use an `Either` type or a `Promise` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
const validPerson = `{"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe"}`;
const invalidPerson = `{"foo": 123}`;

interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

function isPerson(o: any): o is Person {
    return typeof o.firstName === "string" && typeof o.lastName === "string";
}

function getPerson(json: string) {
    const o = JSON.parse(json);

    if (isPerson(o)) {
        return o;
    } else {
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

[Minimal playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20validPerson%20%3D%20%60%7B%22firstName%22%3A%20%22John%22%2C%20%22lastName%22%3A%20%22Doe%22%7D%60%3B%0D%0Aconst%20invalidPerson%20%3D%20%60%7B%22foo%22%3A%20123%7D%60%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Person%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20firstName%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20lastName%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isPerson(o%3A%20any)%3A%20o%20is%20Person%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20typeof%20o.firstName%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22string%22%20%26%26%20typeof%20o.lastName%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22string%22%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getPerson(json%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20o%20%3D%20JSON.parse(json)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(isPerson(o))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20o%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A). Make sure to check turn on `strictNullChecks`

Comment: The function could return anything and it would type check. That's what I'm trying to avoid. Ultimately, I want an interface that says "here are functions that take input arguments and return well-typed results". Basically a service or DAO. I thought doing it straight on the function would be better as a minimal example. Would it help if I included an interface in the example and had it implement that instead?

Comment: @AndrewO inferred type is `Person | undefined`, so everything worked as expected. If you want to enforce it to yourself, specify the return type.

Comment: Updated example to include interface definition.

Comment: it would be nice to generate the `isPerson` type guard from the interface, so that new properties on the interface cause a divergence in the type guard.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is declared in lib.es5.d.ts. Create your own type definition file in your project and declare a new global JSON instance with a definition that returns a dummy type from `parse()` instead of `any`.

This way you will have to use a guard or cast the result in order to avoid a compilation error in functions and methods that have an explicitly defined return type.

```
interface JSONStrict extends JSON {
    /**
      * Converts a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) string into an object.
      * @param text A valid JSON string.
      * @param reviver A function that transforms the results. 
      * This function is called for each member of the object.
      * If a member contains nested objects, the nested objects are
      * transformed before the parent object is.
      */
    parse(text: string, reviver?: (key: any, value: any) => any): { _dummyProp?: void };
}
// overide lib.es5 declaration of JSON
declare const JSON: JSONStrict;

/* ... */
function parseAndThrowCompilationError(): Person {
    var result = JSON.parse('{ "x": 1}');
    return result; 
    // Type '{ _dummyProp?: void }' has no properties in common with type 'Person'
}
```

I added `_dummyProp` to the result because just using an object would match an interface with only optional properties and not throw an error.

... Honestly, this is a bit of a rig and I wonder if the effort is really worth it.