# React + TypeScript union type narrowing using a map instead of if/then

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is a contrived example, but I want to create a generic React component which accepts some common props but with one prop whose type will vary depending on the type passed to it. In this case, the `data` prop will either be `Type1` or `Type2`, and we will know the `type` since it will get passed as a prop.

```
interface BaseProps {
    className: string
}

type SomethingProps = ({type: "type1"; data: Type1} & BaseProps) | ({type: "type2"; data: Type2} & BaseProps)

function Something(props: SomethingProps) {
    const Component = componentMap[props.type];
    return <Component data={props.data} className={props.className} /> // TS Error - 'Type1 | Type2' is not assignable to type 'Type1 & Type2'
}

const componentMap = {
    "type1": Type1Component, // FC<{data: Type1; className: string}>
    "type2": Type2Component // FC<{data: Type2; className: string}>
}
```

This can be easily solved by just doing an if/then check like this

```
function Something(props: SomethingProps) {
  if (props.type === "type1") {
    return <Type1Component data={props.data} className={props.className}/>
  }

  return <Type2Component data={props.data} className={props.className}/>

}
```

But I would like to just use a map instead of an if/then statement. Is such a thing possible without using type casting?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered creating a new type that combines the two common types like this

```
type ComponentType = Type1Component | Type2Component;


const componentMap = {
    "type1": Type1Component,
    "type2": Type2Component
} as const;

function Something(props: SomethingProps) {
    const Component: ComponentType = componentMap[props.type];
    return <Component data={props.data} className={props.className} />
}
```

Another way is using type guards to narrow the type of the data prop based on the value of the type prop. [Narrowing function return type with type guards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522175/narrowing-function-return-type-with-type-guards#52525130)

```
interface BaseProps {
    className: string
}

interface Type1Props {
    type: "type1";
    data: Type1;
}
interface Type2Props {
    type: "type2";
    data: Type2;
}

type SomethingProps = Type1Props | Type2Props & BaseProps;

function isType1(props: SomethingProps): props is Type1Props {
    return props.type === "type1";
}

function Something(props: SomethingProps) {
    const Component = componentMap[props.type];
    if (isType1(props)) {
        return <Component data={props.data} className={props.className} />
    } else {
        return <Component data={props.data} className={props.className} />
    }
}

const componentMap = {
    "type1": Type1Component,
    "type2": Type2Component
} as const;
```

You can also use the typeof operator to make the typeguard a function

```
function isType1(props: SomethingProps): props is Type1Props {
    return typeof props.data === "Type1";
}
```

Comment: Yes doing an if/then type check or using a function to check would work, I would just like to avoid it. And sadly `type ComponentType = Type1Component | Type2Component;` won't work here either since the `data` is expecting `Type1Component & Type2Component`. I think I'll just do the type check like you said, though.